# Atlas of polynomial Galois groups

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, galois-groups

A polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $n$ can be encoded as a finite sequence $(a_0,a_1, \dots, a_n)$, i.e. $p(x)= \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$.
Let $G(a_0,a_1, \dots, a_n)$ be the Galois group of the splitting extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ for $p$.

**Question**: Is there a paper, a website or a software, providing $G(a_0,a_1, \dots, a_n)$ for small $n$ and small $a_i$?

*Remark*: "providing" means like an atlas, it does *not* mean "computing" (see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/22923/34538) for that).

Comment: How small do you want, on either side? $n\leq 10$ and $|a_i|\lt 10$, for instance, is already roughly $10^{13}$ polynomials...

Comment: Fair that! I suspect the computation is harder than I was initially giving it credit for, especially after reading the post you linked to.

Comment: Pari/GP's `polgalois` function can compute Galois groups of polynomials up to degree 11 (if the `galdata` package is installed) according to the doc.

Comment: I don't know if `polgalois` function picks in a database or computes directly the group, but it is much quicker than expected !

Comment: maybe https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/ or the sources where the data comes from https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/Source

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich: this website is really very interesting, so your comment deserves to be written as an answer.